# Django ORM: Get column of DataBaseError

Tags: django, postgresql

Is there a way to get the relevant table and column name, and not just this message?

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(16)
```

I don't like to guess or search the relevant column.

We use django 1.6 and PostgreSQL 9.3.6

Full traceback

```
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1514, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 903, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/f/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(16)
```

Comment: Please show the full error and traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the traceback (the django part).

Comment: I've had something similar and it ended up being a constraint on a field in a third-party app rather than one of mine. Is that possible given the action you're attempting when this happens?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to simply find out.

Django here just quotes what the DB says, and this is a fault of postgres:

```
db=> INSERT INTO db_accesskeys (key, link) VALUES ('AAAAA...', 'BBBBB...');
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(40)
```

postgresql doesn't tell you which one is too long, so there is no way django could find out, too.

A workaround would be to validate every input manually to match the `max_length` (I'm not sure about the exact implementation on django 1.6 though, this is 1.8):

```
def validate_length(model, field, value):
    if len(value) > model._meta.get_field(field).max_length:
        raise Exception(
            field + " of " + model._meta.model_name + " is too long (" + str(len(value)) + " > " +
            str(model._meta.get_field(field).max_length) + ")"
    )


validate_length(AccessKeys, "key", "AAAAAAA...")
Exception: key of accesskeys is too long (109 > 40)
```

You can of course tune the thrown exception to your needs to make it easier to access the field name that's to long, or to see exactly how many chars to long it is or ...

Comment: Is there no way to tell postgres to be more verbose?

Comment: @guettli Proposal to mention column in error messages is currently being discussed by psql developers...